# Is it possible set gnome 3 fallback panel font

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel, gnome-fallback

Is it possible to use a font for the gnome panel which isn't the default font.
I tried to define the font  inside a gnome theme but that doesn't chnge anything and 
if i write something like : gtk-font-name = panel-menu=fontname in ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini nothing change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could *probably* do this by editing the CSS for the panel in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`.
Something like this might work:

```
PanelWidget,
PanelApplet,
PanelToplevel {
    font: Sans 20
}
```

I'm not sure I've got the selector completely correct though. You can look at the Ambiance theme file here at `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/gnome-panel.css`

Comment: Thx it works now.But it doesn't work if i edit the theme file.